# C# How to open a file(workbook) which u saved in a MemoryStream without having it saved actually in a server?

Tags: c#, memory, memorystream

I want to Open a file (show an Excel file for user) without having it saved in my computer/server to open it from memory. So far i came up with this code which saves file to MemoryStream:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
```

So how to open/show a Excel file which is saved in the memory stream

Comment: I strongly suspect you're going to have to save it as a temporary file; Excel isn't going to be able to talk directly to a MemoryStream in another process - you *might* be able to get a named pipe working, but: a temporary file would be *much* easier

Comment: You can use `Path.GetTempFileName()` to get a random filename in the temp area of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel application can't read from a MemoryStream.

You will have to write the file onto disk, maybe into a temporary directory.